# AngularJS 406 not acceptable http post request

Tags: angularjs, json, http, http-post, http-status-code-406

I have a problem with a Post query that I use for a form. I get a "406 not acceptable" error every time I try to validate my form, and Object.data is blank..

```
var edit = function(form){
var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
$ionicLoading.show();
return $http({
       method  : 'POST',
       url     : API.url + '/user',
       headers : {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token},
       transformRequest: function(data, headers){
            console.log(headers);
            headers = angular.extend({}, headers, {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'});
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(angular.toJson(data));
            return angular.toJson(data); // this will go in the body request
            },
           data    : form
   }).then(function(result) {
    console.dir(result.data);
},function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
 });
```

};

I I do not understand why it does not accept..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should to send a json data to your server 
try this following code by adding `'Accept': 'application/json, */*'` to your header:

```
var edit = function(form){
var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
$ionicLoading.show();
return $http({
       method  : 'POST',
       url     : API.url + '/user',
       headers : {
          Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token,
         'Accept': 'application/json, */*'
       },
       transformRequest: function(data, headers){
            console.log(headers);
            headers = angular.extend({}, headers, {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'});
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(angular.toJson(data));
            return angular.toJson(data); // this will go in the body request
            },
           data    : form
   }).then(function(result) {
    console.dir(result.data);
},function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
 });
```